# SELECT TOP 1, 2, 3 RowId from TableWithNRows

Tags: sql-server-2005, loops

Stupid problem and the answer may not exists (Gasp! Groan! Gnash! Teeth!)

I have a select:

```
SELECT * FROM SockDrawer WHERE Color = 'red'
```

This results in 3 rows with row ids of 33896, 35901, 37903 
(A lot of other results too.)

What I want is something like this:

```
DECLARE @ROWID INT --- HOW DO I USE ARRAYS? I'll google but an example would help.
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @LIMIT INT

SELECT * FROM SockDrawer WHERE Color = 'red' 
--(Returns 3 rows. With 3 RowId's 33896, 35901, 33896)

SET @LIMIT = @@ROWCOUNT

SET @COUNT = 1
WHILE @COUNT < @LIMIT BEGIN
  SET @ROWID[0] = (SELECT SockKey From SockDrawer WHERE RowID = 33896)
  SET @ROWID[1] = (SELECT SockKey From SockDrawer WHERE RowID = 35901)
  SET @ROWID[2] = (SELECT SockKey From SockDrawer WHERE RowID = 33896)
  SET @Count = @Count + 1
 END
GO

Then I need to:


SET @COUNT = 0
WHILE @COUNT < @LIMIT 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM SockDrawer WHERE RowID = @ROWID[@COUNT]
    END
GO
```

The trick is I'll never know if I'm dealing with 1 row to delete or 50.

> I'm a dork. I can change. If I want to.

Comment: Can you explain why these three specific rows are more important than all the other rows where color = 'red'?

Comment: That is all the rows. I just need the ID's because I have to use them to get some other SQL fired inside that loop. So I need each RowId for every matching sock. The idea is that I have a bunch of bins and each day I have to balance out each bin so it has 1 of each color. This may happen several times a day. I thought socks would be a simple context.

Comment: So why don't you state your actual problem (I need to delete rows such that there is only one row left for each color), instead of saying "how do I use arrays and here is some non-working code I've tried"?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to train a new BA. I have to run desktop support for the owner's sisters computer and it took me 3 hours to type what you see above without interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about which sock is left for each color, then:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY RowID)
    FROM dbo.SockDrawer
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

If you care which one you keep, adjust the `ORDER BY` accordingly.